# How to write a regular expression to extract the account number from the bank passbook?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need a regular expression to extract the number if my list contains account no and also if my list contains account number. I tried something like this.

```
def check(extracted_text, words): 

    for word in str(extracted_text):
        string_list = word.split()
        word1 , word2, word3 = words
        if (word1 in string_list) and ((word2 in string_list) or (word3 in string_list)):
            print(string_list)

words = ['Account','Number','No'] 
print(check(extracted_text, words))
```

Comment: Can you add examples of text with account numbers and also text with numbers that are not account numbers?

Comment: You tried that, and what happened? How is your current attempt failing to suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below,

```
import re

def check(extracted_text, words):
    for line in extracted_text:
        if re.search("^Account\s+(Number|No)+.*$", line):
                return (line)
```

For more reference on regular expressions,
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: Thank you. But its working for only one case. I will include my extracted text here so that you may clear idea of my needs.  My text is somelike this. I need only Account number and Account name from this.                                              
 'Bank',
 'ROYAPURAM( 94',
 '151, Mannarsamy Koil St.',
 'yapuram',
 'Chennal',
 'Phone No : 25951427',
 'IFSC Code : ID33535300343',
 'इंडियन बैंक',
 'Indian Bank',
 'Your Tech-Friendly Bana',
 'CIE :3061895793',
 'Name : M AMULU',
 'Account No : 6057514202',
 'Address',
 ': OLD NO.127 NO.427',
 'CHENNAI']

Comment: Regular expression not necessary. Without that itself, if someone knows tell me soon. Thanks a lot